# Is it possible to move particular report snapshot to another server in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

In SSRS, is it possible to take backup of particular report snapshot and restore it on another server.

Answer (score -1):

Within your report manager site, there is a 'Download...' option for each report that will let you download a local copy of the report's definition (.rdl) file.
[image: Download .rdl file]

You can then move the .rdl file to a new server and use the 'Upload File' button in the folder to upload that file to the new instance. You will need to create data sources and connections for the report separately.